# mips-openwrt-linux-gcc: link the lua lib error

Tags: lua, openwrt

Sorry for my poor english.

I want to call lua functions in c app on the openwrt 14.07. 
When cross compile the project, i can not find the header and .so files for lua in the toolchain. So i copy the lua51 folder from ubuntu 14.04 and liblua.so from target os to the toolchain.Then try to compile the project, i get the undefined reference errors.

```
mips-openwrt-linux-gcc airkiss.c luaconf.c -lpthread -llua libairkiss_log.a
-L. -o airkiss -Wl,-rpath-link=/opt/OpenWrt-Toolchain-ar71xx-for-mips_34kc-gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib
```

I got the error:

```
luaconf.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `luaL_newstate'
luaconf.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `luaL_openlibs'
luaconf.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `luaL_loadfile'
luaconf.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `lua_getfield'
luaconf.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `lua_pushstring'
luaconf.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `lua_pushstring'
luaconf.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `lua_pcall'
luaconf.c:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `lua_tolstring'
luaconf.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `lua_close'
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to have OpenWrt-style Makefile project to compile your code.

For reference, look at `feeds/packages/multimedia/xupnpd/Makefile` - it also uses liblua.

This manual will help you: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages

Answer (score 0):

It seems lua is enable by default config. Could you check if CONFIG_PACKAGE_liblua  and CONFIG_PACKAGE_lua is 'y' in your .config file?

By default the header file locate at staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include and lib file at staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib.

Also check if you do full build before.